# Editing for SSL - EE1

Tags: control-panel, ee1, fieldtype, ssl

I am trying to force the EE1 control panel to my secure cert, with a bit of difficulty.

The problem is that not everything is delivered by a relative link, so some stuff, specifically custom fieldtypes import their js and css in http:// vs https://

The piece of code that is responsible is:

```
$this->include_css('styles/ngen_file_field.css');
$this->include_js('scripts/jquery.livequery.js');
$this->include_js('scripts/jquery.ngen_file_field.js');
```

etc, for a couple of fieldtypes in there. Each one starts with http://

So with all of this coming in as 'non-secure' the server rules blocks it, not allowing the admin panel to render.

So the question is, how do I override this behaviour? I don't mind circumventing the core stuff, as this site wont be updated ever, and if I have to hard-code something, so help me I will.

Any old EE1 devs have an idea?

Answer (score 3):

You can try making the requests "schemeless"...

Instead of `http://www.example.com/styles/ngen_file_field.css` or `https://www.example.com/styles/ngen_file_field.css` simply edit to:

`//www.example.com/styles/ngen_file_field.css`

This will cause the resources to inherit the scheme of the page in which they are loaded.

Comment: Yes I know that but the http:// is being generated automatically by the code above and inserted into my fieldtypes. I need to know how to subvert the code above so I can run it schemeless.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to getting the fieldtypes all under SSL is to make sure the fieldframe settings are set to https in the fieldtype path.

utilities -> extensions manager -> fieldframe -> settings

.htaccess forces ssl by the below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

---

So to recap, converting an EE1 install to run on https (assuming the ssl cert is correct)

1. Force https via .htaccess
2. Change config file and general preferences to reflect the https:// protocol
3. Change fieldframe settings to the same protocol

The admin panel should all run on ssl now for EE1, for what it is worth this might save someone some time in the future.